# Hover effect works only in firefox

Tags: css, animation, sass, transition

any idea why [this](http://codepen.io/aahamra/pen/cAuCm)  doesn't work in any other browsers apart from Firefox?
I have tried chrome, safari and IE (obviously, it won't work, because nothing does with IE).

thanks!

the SASS code is below, in case it helps:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);

$w: 200;
$h: 180;
$duration: 300ms;
$timing-fn: ease;

$turquoise: #1ABC9C;
$wet-asphalt: #34495E;
$midnight-blue: #2C3E50;
$clouds: #ECF0F1;

* {box-sizing: border-box}

body {background-color: #fff}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif}

.container {
  width: 840px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0 25px;
  color: $wet-asphalt;
  p {
    margin: 0;
    color: transparentize($wet-asphalt, .6);
  }
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 50px;
  &:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
}

li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: #{$w}px;
  height: #{$h}px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  perspective: 500px;

  a  {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  h3 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: transparentize(#fff, .1);
  }
  p  {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: transparentize(#fff, .2);
  }
  .normal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: $clouds;
    color: transparentize($wet-asphalt, .4);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 20px darken($clouds, 2);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: #{$h}px;
    svg {
      pointer-events: none;
      width: 50px;
      path {
        fill: transparentize($wet-asphalt, .8);
      }
    }
  }
  .info {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 4px;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: transparentize($turquoise, .1);
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
  }
}

.in-top .info {
   transform-origin: 50% 0%;
   animation: in-top $duration $timing-fn 0ms 1 forwards;
}
.in-right .info {
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
  animation: in-right $duration $timing-fn 0ms 1 forwards;
}
.in-bottom .info {
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  animation: in-bottom $duration $timing-fn 0ms 1 forwards;
}
.in-left .info {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  animation: in-left $duration $timing-fn 0ms 1 forwards;
}

.out-top .info {
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  animation: out-top $duration $timing-fn 0ms 1 forwards;
}
.out-right .info {
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  animation: out-right $duration $timing-fn 0ms 1 forwards;
}
.out-bottom .info {
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  animation: out-bottom $duration $timing-fn 0ms 1 forwards;
}
.out-left .info {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  animation: out-left $duration $timing-fn 0ms 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes in-top {
  from {transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg);}
  to   {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);}}
@keyframes in-right {
  from {transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg);}
  to   {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);}}
@keyframes in-bottom {
  from {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);}
  to   {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);}}
@keyframes in-left {
  from {transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);}
  to   {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);}}

@keyframes out-top {
  from {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);}
  to   {transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 102deg);}}
@keyframes out-right {
  from {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);}
  to   {transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 102deg);}}
@keyframes out-bottom {
  from {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);}
  to   {transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 101deg);}}
@keyframes out-left {
  from {transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);}
  to   {transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 102deg);}}
```

Comment: Works in Chrome for me.

Comment: IE11 has the same effect as in Firefox but the out-right animation is a bit different.

Comment: @JamieDixon The effect should be in 3D.

Comment: maybe try changing the perspective value to make it "more" 3d?

Comment: It takes *all* of this code to reproduce the problem?